# Boxes in PHP Return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a login form that is ran through different switches so I can have the functions on the same page.

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php");
 if(isset($_POST['process'])) {
     print_r($_POST);
        switch($_POST['process']) {
            case "login":
            echo "Boxes";
            break;
            case "register":
            Register($_POST['user'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['newsletter']);
            break;
            case "forgot_pw":
            ForgotPassword($_POST['user']);
            break;

        }
}
else { ?>
                    <h1>Login</h1><br>
                  <form id="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="login">
                  <p class="error"></p>
                    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Username">
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
                  </form>
<script>
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var continuescript = true;
        var username = $("#user").val();
        var password = $("#pass").val();
        if(username == "") { var continuescript = false; $(".error").html("<i class='fa fa-cross'></i> Username Cannot Be Empty");
            $("#user").css("border-color", "#FF3D3D"); }
        if(password == "") { var continuescript = false; $(".error").append("<p><i class='fa fa-cross'></i> Password Cannot Be Empty</p>"); 
            $("#pass").css("border-color", "#FF3D3D"); }
        if(continuescript == true) {
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $("#login").attr("action"),
                data: $("#login").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The return works fine other than the issue that it returns little boxes around the returned value that will impact the `if(data == "thisdata")` return values. Does anybody know what these boxes are or why they're showing up?
[image]

Comment: looks like encoding problem..? did you set the encoding explicitly ?

Comment: never end your scripts with `?>`, if you don't wait unexpected spaces output. before even you can to set response headers.

Comment: It's best practice to access $_POST variables indirectly using the `filter_input('POST', 'process')` function. Checkout the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) for the types of filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The little boxes are because you have some control characters in the file after the final `?>`. It's often recommended that you don't end a script with `?>`. It's not needed, and if there are invisible characters after it, they'll be sent in the returned data and cause problems like this.

So delete that tag and everything after it. The end of the file should be

```
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what these lines are supposed to be doing `else { ?>` and `<?php } ?>` and they are likely the cause of your encoding issue but it could also be related to the fact that your html is missing all of the `<!DOCTYPE html>` ,`<head>`, `<body>` etc...

The logic I use for stuff like this is something like:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/config.php");

$command = isset($_POST['process']) ? $_POST['process'] : NULL;

switch ($command) {
    case "login":
        echo "Boxes";
        // do some operations, redirect etc...
        exit; // exit instead of break so the rest of the page is not served
    case "register":
        Register($_POST['user'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['newsletter']);
        // do some operations, redirect etc...
        exit;
    case "forgot_pw":
        ForgotPassword($_POST['user']);
        // do some operations, redirect etc...
        exit;
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1><br>

<form id="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="login">

    <p class="error"></p>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
</form>
<script>
    $("#login").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var continuescript = true;
        var username = $("#user").val();
        var password = $("#pass").val();
        if (username == "") {
            var continuescript = false;
            $(".error").html("<i class='fa fa-cross'></i> Username Cannot Be Empty");
            $("#user").css("border-color", "#FF3D3D");
        }
        if (password == "") {
            var continuescript = false;
            $(".error").append("<p><i class='fa fa-cross'></i> Password Cannot Be Empty</p>");
            $("#pass").css("border-color", "#FF3D3D");
        }
        if (continuescript == true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $("#login").attr("action"),
                data: $("#login").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: His issue is with the echoed values for the AJAX calls, not when he's displaying the regular HTML.

Comment: `else { ?>` is used to leave scripting mode and just output raw HTML in the case where it's not an AJAX submission.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I'm not familiar with that syntax, is there somewhere that documents that functionality? This is interesting but I cant seem to find a search term that brings up relevant results on google

Comment: It's not special syntax. You can put `?>` anywhere in a PHP script, and it will start generating plain output. It's just like you did it in your answer, you have `?>` after the end of the `switch`. There's nothing different about using it inside the `else {` block.

Comment: Thanks; the actual fixing issue was putting in the `exit` instead of the `break`, but thanks also for the new syntax for processing. I've never seen it done that way, but I really like it. A lot cleaner.

Comment: Happy to help, but you should note that while my solution works, Barmar's answer actually addresses the problem directly

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the explanation. I did not realize that was the case, good to know